# No puedo cerrar mi programa- un semáforo en java

Tags: java

Muy buenas, estaba jugando con java y me plantee hacer un semaforo (simple,solo usando colores y formas) , pero tengo un problema, al momento de querer cerrarlo no puedo, el programa continua su acción (asumo porque es el hilo que uso). Por favor,me gustaría que me ayuden y me den una solución por favor,gracias.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class lluvia extends JFrame{

public lluvia() {
    super("semaforo");
    setSize(750,650);
    setVisible(true); 
}
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(50, 50, 255, 585);
     for (int i = 0;i < 30;i++) {
         if(i>0 && i<10){
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillArc(100, 100, 100, 100, 0, 360);
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillArc(100, 300, 100, 100, 0, 360);
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillArc(100, 500, 100, 100, 0, 360);
         }
         else if(i>=10 && i<15)
         {
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillArc(100, 100, 100, 100, 0, 360);
            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
            g.fillArc(100, 300, 100, 100, 0, 360);
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillArc(100, 500, 100, 100, 0, 360);
         }
         else if(i>=15 && i<=30){
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillArc(100, 100, 100, 100, 0, 360);
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillArc(100, 300, 100, 100, 0, 360);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillArc(100, 500, 100, 100, 0, 360);
         }
        delaySegundo(); 
    }  
}

public void delaySegundo(){
 try{
     Thread.sleep(1000);
 }catch(InterruptedException e){
  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

return;}
} 
public static void main(String[] args) {
     lluvia l = new lluvia();

               l.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué hilo usas exactamente? No veo que uses algún hilo. Lo que veo es que llamas a `Thread#sleep` lo cual paraliza **toda la aplicación** (que es diferente a hacer que la aplicación ejecute una acción cada cierto tiempo). Además, estás llamando a `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`. Te recomendaría evitar usar ese método a menos que sepas lo que estás haciendo.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que en el atributo de la instancia de la clase lluvia setDefaultCloseOperation deberias poner JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE, de manera :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


lluvia l = new lluvia();

   l.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Comment: si,antes puse esa instancia y paso lo mismo.

Comment: Vale, el fallo es que la interrupcion el hilo principal la estas haciendo en la construccion del objeto. Quiere decir que hasta que no se complete la creacion del objeto lluvia , el programa no respondera a nada, y tendras que esperar a que se complete el bucle, luego ya puedes cerrarla. Para evitar(no estoy seguro) esto debes replantear la clase y hacer el cambio de colores y esferas en un metodo aparte , que podras llamar ahora si con un bucle y una interrupcion desde el metodo main, o incluso en otro metodo de la misma clase lluvia, pero que este metodo no sea llamado al crearse el objeto

Comment: Ojo , el fallo es ese que te dije,que no es un fallo en si , ya que funciona bien , es un fallo de diseño de la clase, la solucion , no estoy seguro si es correcta

Comment: Por cierto, cuando un metodo devuelve el valor void, no debes de poner "return", (es solo una buena practica de programacion, al menos en java) y los if-else encadenados el ultimo deberia de ser solo "else" no "else if", comoo te digo no son errores en si , pero si lo son de diseño del codigo